# Riemann to InfluxDB event drop

Tags: events, timestamp, logstash, influxdb, riemann

I have a simple setup which uses filebeat and topbeat to forward data to Logstash, which further forwards it to Riemann, which in turn sends it to InfluxDB 0.9. I use Logstash to split an event into multiple events, all of  which show up on Riemann logs (with the same timestamp). However, only one of these split events reaches my InfluxDB. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

In InfluxDB 0.9, a point is uniquely identified by the measurement name, full tag set, and the timestamp. If another point arrives later with identical measurement name, tag set, and timestamp, it will silently overwrite the previous point. This is intentional behavior.

Since your timestamps are identical and you're writing to the same measurement, you must ensure that your tag set differs for each point you want to record. Even something like `fuzz=[1,2,3,4,5]` will work to differentiate the points.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.

Comment: Note that in InfluxDB 0.10 the behavior has changed. Overwriting a point now generates a new point with the union of the two field sets from each point.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the timely update! I read about it today, and unexpectedly came upon your answer to my question :D